# .Net Socket Service :: Is passing socket requests through events a silly idea for large scale services?

Tags: c#, sockets

Most people seem to build a listener socket and will include "events" to be invoked for processing. EG: SocketConnected, DataReceived. The programmer initializes a listener and binds to the "events" methods to receive socket events to build the service.

I feel on a large scale implementation, it would be more efficient to avoid delegates in the listener. And to complete all the processing in the callback methods. Possibly using different call backs for receiving data based on the knowledge of knowing what command is coming next. (This is part of my Message Frame Structure)

I have looked around for highly scalable examples, but I only find the standard MSDN implementations for asynchronous sockets or variations from other programmers that replicate the MSDN example.

Does anyone have any good experience that could point me in the right direction?

---

Note> The service will hold thousands of clients and in most cases, the clients stayed connected and updates received by the service will be send out to all other connected clients. It is a synchronized P2P type system for an object orientated database.

Comment: Do you mean anonymous methods (e.g. lambda) ?  You can't have a callback without a delegate.

Comment: I'm not sure to tell you the truth. In the System.Net.Sockets.Socket namespace I use the asynchronous methods that start with Begin for all my operations. The methods themselves take a delegate argument that is called when the operation completes. In most cases, when the delegate is fired upon completion, the service breaks the stream into messages and calls an event to trigger the message processing.

Comment: @mathewdunn I'm not really sure what you question is; but I've tried to answer what I think it may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between an event call and a callback is negligible.  A callback is just the invocation of a delegate (or a function pointer).  You can't do asynchronous operation without some sort of callback and expect to get results of any kind.

With events, they can be multicast.  This means multiple callback calls--so that would be more costly because you calling multiple methods.  But, if you're doing that you probably need to do it--the alternative is to have multiple delegates and call them manually.  So, there'd be no real benefit.  Events can often include sender/eventargs; so, you've got that extra object and the creation of the eventargs instance; but I've never seen a situation where that affected performance.

Personally, I don't use the event-based asynchronous pattern--I've found (prior to .NET 4.5) that the asynchronous programming model to be more ubiquitous.  In .NET 4.5 I much prefer the task asynchronous pattern (single methods that end in Async instead of two methods one starting with Begin and one starting with End) because they can be used with async/await and less wordy.

Now, if the question is the difference between `new AsyncCallback(Async_Send_Receive.Read_Callback)` e.g.:

```
s.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0, 
                                     new AsyncCallback(Async_Send_Receive.Read_Callback), so);
```

and just `Async_Send_Receive.Read_Callback` e.g.:

```
s.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, 0, 
                                     Async_Send_Receive.Read_Callback, so);
```

The second is just a short-hand of the first; the `AsyncCallback` delegate is still created under the covers.

But, as with most things; even if it's generally accepted not to be noticeably different in performance, test and measure.  If one way has more benefits (included performance) than another, use that one.

Comment: Hello Peter, great advise. Just what I looking for. Thanking you. Do you have a good link to the new async features in .NET 4.5?

Comment: Using async/await http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg440604.aspx the task asynchronous pattern http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957 and loads of asynchronous stuff in 4.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My only advice to you is this: Go with the style that provides the most clarity.

Eliminating an entire language feature because of an unmeasured speed difference would be premature. The cost of method calls/delegate invocations is highly unlikely to be the bottleneck in your code. Sure, you could benchmark the relative cost of one versus another, but if your program is only spending 1% of its setting up method invocations, then even huge differences won't really affect your program.

My best advice to you if you really want to juice your server, just make sure that *all* your IO happens asynchronously, and never run long-running tasks in the threadpool. .net4.5 async/await really simplifies all of this... consider using it for more maintainable code.

Comment: Thank you for your advise so far. My service is 100% asynchronous processing, but does not use wait handles in a the begin accept method. I use the callback to begin the next begin accept.

Comment: Btw: I am more considering the memory to register 10,000+ x 4 delegates for each socket. Where it could be simply 4 static methods that pass pointers to each socket for processing.

Comment: I have also made my own buffer processor that avoids joining \ building multiple byte[] arrays for transmition. My tests show on a 1,000,000 loop building a 20 byte packet, to be between 3-4 times as efficient as using IEnumerable and LINQ to join the byte arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with live betting systems using sockets and with two way active messaging. It is really easier to work with a framework to handle the socket layer like WCF P2P. It handles all the connection problems for you and you can concentrate on your bussiness logic.

Comment: I have looked into WFC for this project. Unfortunately it is unable to meet some of my requirements and is not viable solution to solve my problem. :(

Comment: :( too bad. Good luck for you.